# How to eliminate space between rows of dots in my slideshow. I have about 2.5 inches between the rows. I have 120 slides causing three rows of dots

Tags: html, css

How to eliminate space between rows of dots in my slideshow? I have about 2.5 inches between the rows. I have 120 slides causing three rows of dots.

The slideshow is of veterans in our cemetery and I would also like to place a letter on top or on the bottom of a dot if the dot represents a new letter of the alphabet.

```css
.dot { 
    cursor: pointer;  height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%; line-height: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}
```

The web page in question is: [https://www.mountbrydges.ca/Remembrance Slideshow 3.html](https://www.mountbrydges.ca/Remembrance%20Slideshow%203.html)

Comment: Make pls a minimally reproducible example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS contains the line `margin: 100px auto;`. This adds 100px of margin above and below each of your dots. Reduce this to a smaller value (even 0) and your dots will be close together.

I suspect you added this space to move the dots below the slide but because you added it to the `.dot` class it's applied to every dot. You need to apply the margin to the div that contains the dots, not the dots themselves.

Adding a letter to the dots is a very different question, and can't be done purely in HTML and CSS - you'll need to do it manually or in the code that generates the slideshow.

Comment: Not sure of the jargon "Apply the margin to the div that contains the dots. not the dots themselves". Must I add it to this line ? <div class="slideshow-container" align="center" max-width: 800px;  >    or  in this section                                                                     
     <div class="mySlides fade" >
    <span class="style13"> Dorothy M. Smith - Adcock</span>
    <br /><br />
    <img src="Slideshow Adcock, Alton Glen ; Smith, Dorothy M. ; Adcock, Billy ; Adcock, Jerrold (IMG_3578).jpg" >  </div> I have solved the issue with the spacing. Thanks.

Comment: Trial and error wins the day. It's working!! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got there. Sometimes, trial and error is the only way!  (As you now know, "apply the margin to the div containing the dots" means adding a class to the `<div>` element that surrounds the dots, that includes `margin: 100px auto;`.)

Comment: After some more testing I found out that it works fine until the second row of dots and then the first row jumps up to over/under the slide. Once I start the third row the second row jumps up to over/under the slide just below the first row. Something still does not work 100%.  This is where I added the line                                                .active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
  margin-top: 100px; 
}                           and I cannot point to the dots on the second and third row. The rows of dots start flashing really really fast.

Comment: Checking the code on your site linked from the question (which you've fortunately updated), the problem is that you're still applying the 100px margin in the `.dot:hover` definition in your CSS. This means that, when you hover over the dot, extra margin is being applied. This pushes it away from your pointer, removing the hover and thus the margin. Repeat indefinitely! You really shouldn't apply margin in `:hover` definitions because it'll lead to this sort of problem.

Comment: I think (hope) it will continue to work now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Fingers crossed for you! If the answer worked, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin` from the styling of dots i.e.

```
.dot {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Add `margin-top` to the div encapsulating all the dots.

```
margin-top: 100px;
```

Comment: Great that worked now I have to get the dots below the slides working. I'm not sure of your jargon "div encapsulating all the dots" See my comment to @John